# Where to save username , password if you have just 5 members to use it ?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a website which needs to give login access to staff member's and clients of company. But maximum number of staff that will use system are 5. I am confuse while designing such a system whether different table in database make any sense for staff login. If not in database where this login credentials can be saved successfully to create login system?

Comment: whether it's 5 or 5000 security should still be the same. You should use an established registration/signup system rather than doing it from scratch

Comment: And general security warning: You _never_ store user passwords in a database. Never. What you do store is a _hash_ of the password. Then, at authentication time, you again hash the provided password and _compare the two hashes_. That way you don't loose your users passwords even if your system gets compromised.

Comment: maintain json file it would really handy in php or in javascript.....

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap A file based credentials store is working, yes, but much slower than a database connection. And changes to that file are _much_ more complex to implement. So that rarely does make sense, especially if you need a database connection anyway.

Comment: @arkascha file based credentials would much and more faster than database....only matter how you handle it.

Comment: Go for table always - now you have 5 people. And after one year? Some of them may be gone, some new may come, your app will be used by other department etc. Never trust any "axioms" given at the beginning of development. In half a year or year you can be asked for totally opposite behavior of the app...

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap Are you sure about json file ? because json is used for data exchange. I never heard that anyone uses json to store password , is it secure thing to do.

Comment: @arkascha Yes, I am using sha() to store password.

Comment: @arkascha,@Republic I am sorry i might be wrong, but i was thinking json is pretty simple to handle in as i known language like js,php,node..so i suggested...

Comment: @abhijitjagtag any file based solution will be slower than a database eequest, simply because file handling funcrion need Hardware access which is always extremely slow. A database connection is already open.

Comment: @repulic the sha algirithm encrypts, it is not a hashing algorithmus.

Comment: @arkascha sha is hashing algorithm Refer here : http://www.securityinnovationeurope.com/blog/whats-the-difference-between-hashing-and-encrypting

Comment: @repulic Indeed, you are right, I got confused with the algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

> I am confuse while designing such a system whether different table in database make any sense for staff login.

Yes, it makes. Go for a table in database. The problem solved.